# How can I use a wildcard SSL certificate when setting up ISP Config?

Tags: debian, ssl, web-server, virtualhost, linode

I am running a Linode Debian 8 server. My web site directory is set up under a different virtual host that is different from the default. /var/www/html/example.com/public_html This is way ISP config sets it up, I believe.

I found a guide at

```
https://www.ispconfig.org/blog/the-perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/
```

thanks to someone on a mailing list. I have a question.

How can I make all connections use https? When I set up the configuration for the first time, it created a couple of self-signed certificates. This causes web browsers and e-mail clients to give people a scary warning message about the site not being secure. How can I tailor these instructions for use with a commercial, wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the ISPConfig stuff since that's going to have it's own way of doing things and you should probably check their docs first.

> How can I make all connections use https?

Configure apache with a rewrite or redirect rule to force all connections to HTTPS

> How can I tailor these instructions for use with a commercial, wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy?

No idea. But instead of using a self-signed certificate, go buy a wild-card certificate and use that instead. Typically you'll have to provide a CSR to GoDaddy for this. You should end-up with two files, a private key and a certificate. Just put these in the right configuration directives in the Apache configuration for your VirtualHost; or go check ISPConfig's docs on how to do this. Since this tutorial also has configuration for a ton of other services, you'll have to add directives for those as well.